# Local variables in Bash script to be run by Cron

Tags: bash, cron, raspberry-pi

I have a bash script which loops through a list of filenames in a text file, deduces a date from the filename and then calls a library script (./dropbox_uploader.sh delete [filname]) to conditionally delete a remote file in my Dropbox account using Dropbox's api. The condition is simply whether the file is older than [n] days. n is passed into the script in position $2. $1 is a text file containing the entries.

2 local variables, $go and $stay count the instances of where a file is eligible for deletion, or not. At the end of my script, I fire off an email via the mail program using the values of the 2 variables..

My problem is that if I run this from the command line everything works just fine and the email reads:

> "The dropbox files were purged: 554 files deleted and 310 were kept."

However, if the script is run via Cron using my user's crontab then it seems that the local variables are both zero / null, and the email is:

> The dropbox files were purged: 0 files deleted and 0 were kept.

I can run the script again manually after the cron run and the variables are non zero.

I think I'm missing something fundamental about the way cron runs for the user and would be grateful for suggestions.

My script:

```
#!/bin/bash
threshold=$(date -d "$2 days ago" +%s)
go=0
stay=0
rm /home/pi/Dropbox-Uploader/camDeleteLog.txt
echo "deleting older than $2 days ago ..."

while IFS='' read -r line || [[-n "$line" ]]; do
        line=$(echo $line | xargs)      # trim spaces from the filename, just i$
        y=${line:0:4}
        m=${line:5:2}
        d=${line:8:2}
        #echo "Filedate is $y-$m-$d"
        seconds=$(date -d "$y-$m-$d" +%s)

        if ((seconds < threshold))
        then
                echo "Deleting file $go, $line"
                ((go++))
                ###echo "./dropbox_uploader.sh delete \"$line\""
               ./dropbox_uploader.sh delete "$line" >> /home/pi/Dropbox-Upload$

        else
                echo "$line is too new to delete"
                ((stay++))
        fi
done < "$1"
echo "The dropbox files were purged: $go files deleted and $stay were kept." | $
```

My crontab for user pi:

```
0 */8 * * * /home/pi/Dropbox-Uploader/moveVideostoDropbox.py # JOB_ID_1
0 0,6,12,18 * * * Dropbox-Uploader/processDBFiles.sh # JOB_ID_2
0 1,7,13,19 * * * Dropbox-Uploader/processByDate.sh camfiles.txt 2 # JOB_ID_3
```

Job 3 is the one that does the date processing and deleting.
Jobs 2 and 3 were originally run together but I suspected (wrongly) that this was the root of my problem so split the 2 and ran them an hour apart as an experiement - Job 2 will never take more than 1 hour to run.

Comment: You are using relative paths in the script. Do you know what directory is your working directory when the script is run by cron? You could have `cd "$HOME/somedir"` early in your script to make sure that you are in the correct directory when the script runs.

Comment: OK, helpful replies, thank you. I will go and do some more investigating. Incidentally, although I have resorted back to editing cron using "crontab -e", there is a cron management app I installed on my Pi. When you edit a script via the app it warns:
 "Note about working directory of executed tasks: Recurrent tasks will be run from the home directory." 
This is the reason I referenced the script to run from the home/pi directory. But I will look at making sure I've got proper absolute paths.

Comment: I wonder if the pi uses `sh` by default for cron jobs?

Comment: Jeff - good point. Researching how to determine cron shell has taken me to https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/2167. I'll follow that up too. Thanks.

Comment: None of the crontab entries you have shown us have 2 arguments

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced similar issues with `cron` jobs. I cannot specifically say what is wrong with your `cron` entry, but I will share some thoughts of what I have noticed about the differences between `cron` running a script, and an interactive shell running a script.

First, `cron` does NOT read your local environment, the default `PATH`is, I believe, `/usr/bin:/usr/sbin`.
One test to try is to print your environment variables at the beginning of the script and run interactively, then run from the cron and see the difference.

```
#!/bin/bash
env
```

Second, do not assume that you are running from your home directory. Specify ALL path names. 
i.e. `/bin/date`, `/home/pi/scriptname.sh /home/pi/filename`, etc.

Third, try sourcing your local environment in the script and/or try add the `-f` option to your shebang

```
#!/bin/bash
. /home/pi/.bashrc  #Not the period space at the beginning of the line
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash -f
```

Fourth, check the log output of the script to be sure it is processing the right files and actually setting your variables. You can do this by reading the `cron` log (wherever you have that set to log to), or redirect STDIN & STDOUT to a file:

```
0 1,7,13,19 * * * /home/pi/Dropbox-Uploader/processByDate.sh /home/pi/camfiles.txt 2 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: The `PATH` may be _different_, but it will be _sane_, i.e. there's definitely no need to specify full paths to standard utilities like `date`.  Also note that if the script needs to have access to other directories usually found in `PATH`, it is free to modify that variable itself.  Sourcing `.bashrc` from a script is not really a good solution as that file is supposed to set up an interactive environment, which may include starting things like `screen` or `tmux`...

Comment: Permanently sourcing .bashrc is, as you say, not a good idea. This is only meant to be a troubleshooting step if it works when sourcing your local environment then your environment contains something your script needs.
There is a .bashrc and a .bash_profile. One is for interactive, the other is for non-interactive. I'd assume the OP knows if his profile  I have seen instances where they did not work correctly without them. It doesn't hurt to do it. Some standard utilities are both builtin and executable file. Specifying a path forces to executable (consider the echo command).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the while-loop is implemented in a subshell.  Here's [a thead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16854280/a-variable-modified-inside-a-while-loop-is-not-remembered) that discusses it and a potential proper solution.

But I've been frustrated by this problem enough that I try to avoid it altogether.  Using a  file to hold variables won't win points for elegance, but it works.  This little script illustrates it.

```
#!/bin/bash
c=0
FILE=/tmp/$(basename $0).$$
while IFS= read -r line; do
    ((c++))
    echo "count=$c" > $FILE
done < somefile
. $FILE
echo "Read $count lines"
rm -f $FILE
```

Comment: OK, as Ken Jackson says, the while loop is implemented in a subshell. I've now written my variables to a file inside the loop and then later used the result from calls to AWK  to echo the values into the text string which is the body of the email.
What I can't now figure out is why the while loop variables are valid outside the loop when I run the script manually from the shell, but not when triggered by Cron. I think that's a separate question!